# How to find out all directories mounted on /dev/md1

Tags: mount, partition, disk

My root partition is full. How do I find all directories which are mounted on /dev/md1?

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.6G   14G  11% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1         20G   17G  1.9G  90% /
/dev/md2        421G   13G  387G   4% /home
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Since devices are mounted on directories and not the other way round, I can hardly understand your question. As you put it / is the mount point for /dev/md1. Then if I understand you want to list all directories behind / belonging to /dev/md1 then cd / and tree -x should answer your question.

Comment: However, if your problem is about space, you might prefer listing those associated to high space usage. Therefore du -hx could be another valid option. But once again, please clarify your question.

Comment: @MC68020 thanks, figure it out the actual command tree -f -L 1

Comment: "devices are mounted on directories and not the other way round" Thanks for correcting the direction of mounting ;)

Comment: tree -f -L 1 ? Well you **want the  x option** in order for your list not to cross filesystems.

Comment: What you want to find is the directories that are using the most space and not all directories. The most likely culprits are the `/var` directory or `/var/log` and `/var/lib` in particular and possibly `/var/tmp`.